# Shifting tiles in a puzzle game

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to make a puzzle game but the problem is that I can't do the EventHandler setOnMouseClicked.Also I want to know how to make possible that to re-arrange the puzzle so it shows random images in every-coordinate. This is how far I got.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class eliss extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ImageView view[][] = new ImageView[5][5];
    Image imag = new Image("http://images.cdn.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/gallery_slide/public/ferrari-laferrari-zfye-059_1.jpg?itok=hfLNxUD9",600,600,false,true);

    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setVgap(2);
    pane.setHgap(2);

    PuzzleImage(view, imag, pane);


    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,1100,1100);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Elis");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
  public static void main(String[] x)
  {
    launch(x);
  }

public void PuzzleImage( ImageView view[][],Image imag,GridPane pane)
{
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {

    if(j==4 && i==4) view[i][j]=null;
    else{
    view[i][j]=new ImageView(imag);
    Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D(120*i,120*j,120,120);
    view[i][j].setViewport(rect);
    pane.add(view[i][j], i, j);
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is too much for a question on StackOverflow. However, I got a little bit of spare time, so I quickly drafted up some code to demonstrate what you need:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PuzzleGame extends Application {

    private Image image = new Image("http://images.cdn.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/gallery_slide/public/ferrari-laferrari-zfye-059_1.jpg?itok=hfLNxUD9",600,600,false,true);

    private static double SCENE_WIDTH = 1024;
    private static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 768;

    public static int TILE_ROW_COUNT = 5;
    public static int TILE_COLUMN_COUNT = 5;
    public static double TILE_SIZE = 120;

    public static double offsetX = (SCENE_WIDTH - TILE_ROW_COUNT * TILE_SIZE) / 2;
    public static double offsetY = (SCENE_HEIGHT - TILE_COLUMN_COUNT * TILE_SIZE) / 2;

    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create grid
        for (int x = 0; x < TILE_ROW_COUNT; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < TILE_COLUMN_COUNT; y++) {

                // create tile
                ImageView tile = new ImageView(image);
                Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D(TILE_SIZE * x, TILE_SIZE * y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                tile.setViewport(rect);

                // consider empty cell, let it remain empty
                if (x == (TILE_ROW_COUNT - 1) && y == (TILE_COLUMN_COUNT - 1)) {
                    tile = null;
                }

                cells.add(new Cell(x, y, tile));
            }
        }

        // shuffle cells
        shuffle();

        // create playfield
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // put tiles on playfield, assign event handler
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {

            Cell cell = cells.get(i);

            Node imageView = cell.getImageView();

            // consider empty cell
            if (imageView == null)
                continue;

            // click-handler: swap tiles, check if puzzle is solved
            imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> {

                moveCell((Node) mouseEvent.getSource());

            });

            // position images on scene
            imageView.relocate(cell.getLayoutX(), cell.getLayoutY());

            pane.getChildren().add(cell.getImageView());
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * Swap images of cells randomly
     */
    public void shuffle() {

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            int a = rnd.nextInt(cells.size());
            int b = rnd.nextInt(cells.size());

            if (a == b)
                continue;

            // skip bottom right cell swap, we want the empty cell to remain there
            if( cells.get(a).isEmpty() || cells.get(b).isEmpty())
                continue;

            swap( cells.get(a), cells.get(b));

        }

    }

    public void swap( Cell cellA, Cell cellB) {

        ImageView tmp = cellA.getImageView();
        cellA.setImageView(cellB.getImageView());
        cellB.setImageView(tmp);

    }

    public boolean checkSolved() {

        boolean allSolved = true;

        for (Cell cell : cells) {

            if (!cell.isSolved()) {
                allSolved = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Solved: " + allSolved);

        return allSolved;
    }

    public void moveCell(Node node) {

        // get current cell using the selected node (imageview)
        Cell currentCell = null;
        for (Cell tmpCell : cells) {
            if (tmpCell.getImageView() == node) {
                currentCell = tmpCell;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (currentCell == null)
            return;

        // get empty cell
        Cell emptyCell = null;

        for (Cell tmpCell : cells) {
            if (tmpCell.isEmpty()) {
                emptyCell = tmpCell;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (emptyCell == null)
            return;

        // check if cells are swappable: neighbor distance either x or y must be 1 for a valid move
        int steps = Math.abs(currentCell.x - emptyCell.x) + Math.abs(currentCell.y - emptyCell.y);
        if (steps != 1)
            return;

        System.out.println("Transition: " + currentCell + " -> " + emptyCell);

        // cells are swappable => create path transition
        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().add(new MoveToAbs(currentCell.getImageView(), currentCell.getLayoutX(), currentCell.getLayoutY()));
        path.getElements().add(new LineToAbs(currentCell.getImageView(), emptyCell.getLayoutX(), emptyCell.getLayoutY()));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(100));
        pathTransition.setNode(currentCell.getImageView());
        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.NONE);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(1);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);

        final Cell cellA = currentCell;
        final Cell cellB = emptyCell;
        pathTransition.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> {

            swap( cellA, cellB);

            checkSolved();

        });

        pathTransition.play();

    }

    private static class Cell {

        int x;
        int y;

        ImageView initialImageView;
        ImageView currentImageView;

        public Cell(int x, int y, ImageView initialImageView) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.initialImageView = initialImageView;
            this.currentImageView = initialImageView;
        }

        public double getLayoutX() {
            return x * TILE_SIZE + offsetX;
        }

        public double getLayoutY() {
            return y * TILE_SIZE + offsetY;
        }

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return currentImageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
            this.currentImageView = imageView;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return currentImageView == null;
        }

        public boolean isSolved() {
            return this.initialImageView == currentImageView;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
        }

    }

    // absolute (layoutX/Y) transitions using the pathtransition for MoveTo
    public static class MoveToAbs extends MoveTo {

        public MoveToAbs(Node node) {
            super(node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2, node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
        }

        public MoveToAbs(Node node, double x, double y) {
            super(x - node.getLayoutX() + node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2, y - node.getLayoutY() + node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
        }

    }

    // absolute (layoutX/Y) transitions using the pathtransition for LineTo
    public static class LineToAbs extends LineTo {

        public LineToAbs(Node node, double x, double y) {
            super(x - node.getLayoutX() + node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2, y - node.getLayoutY() + node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) to generate a random permutation of a `List` This can be used to place the tiles in a random order:

```
private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 5;
private static final int ROW_COUNT = 5;

private static void fillGridPane(GridPane pane, ImageView[][] view, Image imag) {
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>(24);
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_COUNT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, end = i == (COLUMN_COUNT - 1) ? ROW_COUNT - 1 : ROW_COUNT; j < end; j++) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(imag);
            images.add(iv);
            view[i][j] = iv;
            Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D(120 * i, 120 * j, 120, 120);
            iv.setViewport(rect);
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(images);
    Iterator<ImageView> iter = images.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_COUNT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, end = i == (COLUMN_COUNT - 1) ? ROW_COUNT - 1 : ROW_COUNT; j < end; j++) {
            pane.add(iter.next(), i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

The `onMouseClicked` event handler can be attached to the `GridPane` and [`MouseEvent.getTarget`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#getTarget--) can be used to get the node that was clicked:

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (move(event)) {
        if (checkWin()) {
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "You Win!").show();
        }
    }
});
```

```
private int emptyTileX = 4;
private int emptyTileY = 4;

private boolean move(MouseEvent event) {
    Object target = event.getTarget();

    if (target instanceof ImageView) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) target;
        int row = GridPane.getRowIndex(iv);
        int column = GridPane.getColumnIndex(iv);

        int dx = Math.abs(column - emptyTileX);
        int dy = Math.abs(row - emptyTileY);

        if ((dx == 0 && dy == 1) || (dx == 1 && dy == 0)) {
            // swap image and empty tile, if they are next to each other
            GridPane.setConstraints(iv, emptyTileX, emptyTileY);
            emptyTileX = column;
            emptyTileY = row;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To check the winning condition, you can simply check the positions of the `ImageView`s in the `GridPane`

```
private boolean checkWin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_COUNT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, end = i == (COLUMN_COUNT - 1) ? ROW_COUNT - 1 : ROW_COUNT; j < end; j++) {
            ImageView iv = view[i][j];
            if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(iv) != i || GridPane.getRowIndex(iv) != j) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```